# Getting error with sql named query when trying a batch insert

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-sql

```
from("{{my.app.source}}")
                .unmarshal()
                .bindy(BindyType.Csv, EmployeeCsvRecord.class)
                .split(body())
                .streaming()
                .bean("employeeService", "getMap")
                .aggregate(constant(true), new EmployeeAggregationStrategy())
                .completionSize(500)
                .log("data ready to insert into database")
                .to("{{sql.insertEmployee}}")
                .log("data inserted into database");


"sql:insert = into employee (employeeName, employeeAge, employeeGender, employeeDepartment, employeeSalary) values (:#employeeName, :#employeeAge, :#employeeGender, :#employeeDepartment, :#employeeSalary);batch=true"
```

> Cannot find key [employeeName] in message body or headers to use when setting named parameter in query

I tried with batch false it is working fine.
I have to do it only with sql component otherwise there are multiple ways available.

Comment: The doc says : "*if batch is set to true, then the interpretation of the inbound message body changes slightly – instead of an iterator of parameters, the component expects an iterator that contains the parameter iterators*". Is this what your EmployeeAggregationStrategy is returning ?

Comment: It is returning a list of maps